# Modules / typing variable with resource from another provider

Tags: terraform, launchdarkly

I am creating a tf module to abstract some of the launch darkly configuration in terraform.

I have defined one of my modules variables as `feature_flags` which essentially is a `map` of `launchdarkly_feature_flag` resources.

At the moment I am to manually provide type safety to this variable,
however I was wondering if there was a way of passing a type from the launchdarkly_provider.

```
# now                          |   # expected
                               |
                               |   variable "feature_flags" {
variable "feature_flags" {     |     type = map(launchdarkly_feature_flags)
  type = map(any)              |   }
}                              |
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know what you’re looking for is not possible using Terraform. One of the reasons I guess is that Terraform’s type system is not complex enough to fully represent a resource, some arguments (e.g. blocks, `provider`, or lifecycle configuration) cannot be expressed using the current type system. If you’re willing to go down a rabbit hole however, you may be more strict about what you accept by defining a more stricter type:

```
variable "feature_flags" {
  type = map(object({
    description = optional(string)
    tags        = optional(map(string))
    temporary   = optional(bool)
    # etc.
  }))
}
```